# Bluetooth not pairing

Tags: bluetooth, inspiron, sony

I am trying to pair my Bluetooth headset, but I can only see the device for a second and then it disappears, other times (like now) it won't detect the headset at all.
I was able to pair a few times before, but this time it just won't connect.
The headphones are Sony MDR-ZX220BT and I have a Dell Inspiron 5521 with Ubuntu 18.04.
I have Kernel 4.15.0-43-generic.
The wireless controller is Intel Corporation Wireless 3160 (rev 83) with Bluetooth included.
I'm dual booting with Windows 7, the headset didn't work there either, but then I installed updated drivers released by Intel, and the headset works just fine.

Here is some info:
I was getting more info with the following command before, but now it just says that another instance is already running.

```
:~$ blueman-applet --loglevel debug
blueman-applet version 2.0.5 starting
There is an instance already running
```

I tried the following:

```
bluetoothctl
power off
power on
scan on
```

And I get this:

```
Discovery started
[CHG] Controller 2C:6E:85:76:4C:FA Discovering: yes
[NEW] Device 00:18:09:70:74:E4 MDR-ZX220BT
[bluetooth]# pair 00:18:09:70:74:E4
Attempting to pair with 00:18:09:70:74:E4
Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.InProgress
```

Additional info:

```
:~$ systemctl status bluetooth.service
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2019-01-26 10:36:52 GMT; 11min ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 1826 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─1826 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

ene 26 10:36:52 gabo bluetoothd[1826]: Bluetooth daemon 5.50
ene 26 10:36:52 gabo bluetoothd[1826]: Starting SDP server
ene 26 10:36:52 gabo bluetoothd[1826]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized
ene 26 10:36:52 gabo systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
ene 26 10:36:52 gabo systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
ene 26 10:37:12 gabo bluetoothd[1826]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.137 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
ene 26 10:37:12 gabo bluetoothd[1826]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.137 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
ene 26 10:47:30 gabo bluetoothd[1826]: Pair device timed out for hci0
```

More info:

```
:~$ pactl list short | grep blue
8   module-bluetooth-policy     
9   module-bluetooth-discover       
10  module-bluez5-discover
```

More info:

```
:~$ rfkill
ID TYPE      DEVICE      SOFT      HARD
 0 wlan      phy0   unblocked unblocked
 1 bluetooth hci0   unblocked unblocked
```

More info:

```
:~$ rfkill list bluetooth
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

So I'm not sure where to go from here.
Any help is appreciated !

Comment: No solutions yet?